# flash cs3 symbol rename issue "1120 access of undefined property"

Tags: actionscript-3, undefined, rename, flash-cs3, document-class

I'm working off an old game project and have changed symbol name 'Treasure' to 'Food' and the images inside the symbol.

Strangely the game runs fine without changing 'Treasure inside the actionscript file...

Then in the documentClass actionscript file where I change the instance of hitting a 'Treasure' to 'Food' I get the "1120: Access of undefined property Food." at..

```
if (otherObjects[objectNum] is Food)
```

Is there somewhere which I have to clear all links to symbols or something? :/ The actionscript file is definitely the one associated with the .fla - I opened it straight through the .fla's documentClass field

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you still have exported that asset for Actionscript as "Treasure". Rename it to "Food" if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I found it in Linkage when you right click on the symbol. The class name was still 'Treasure'!